# Attempt to present controller whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have created controllers using XIB files and am trying to load the controllers from the initial rootviewController. I included table views , and in file's owner , I mentioned the class name , and dragged the file owner to the view as well. My code is

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    NSLog("It did enter the didselectRowAtIndexPath")
    if (indexPath.section == 0){
        let enrolledView = DetailsViewController()
        let top : UIViewController = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController)!
        top.presentViewController(enrolledView, animated: true, completion: {
            NSLog("Loading Details view controller")
        })
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 1){
        let appcatalog = AppCatalogViewController()
        let top : UIViewController = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController)!
        top.presentViewController(appcatalog, animated: true, completion: {NSLog("Loading web View")})
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 2){
        let support = supportViewController()
        let top : UIViewController = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController)!
        top.presentViewController(support, animated: true, completion: {
            NSLog("Loading the supportViewController")
        })
    }


}
```

But still there is this warning(mentioned as the title) and the screen remans the same .Can anyone help ? thank you in advance.

Comment: why you don't try to present from self

Comment: I had it that way , and saw in one of the questions that might not be the rootviewcontroller or something and suggestion was to change the code this way , but the warning remains the same for either ways..!

Comment: see this http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-avoid-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy-error-when-presenting-a-uiviewcontroller/

Comment: I saw the same post and changed it to self.presentViewControlelr .... but , even then the warning was there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a UITableView in your xib ?

In that case, the owner file which is the UIViewController must add this view to the hierarchy.

In the viewDidLoad of the UIViewController, add :

```
self.view.addSubView(myTableView)
```

myTableView should be an IBOutlet to your TableView

Comment: I ain't using storyboards.

Comment: Well, you should be able to use IBOutlets in Interface Builder too